# Can a full DBCC CHECKDB operation be safely offloaded to an AG secondary server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Can a full DBCC CHECKDB operation be safely offloaded to an AG secondary server?  Would be nice to not have this overhead on the primary server.

SQL2019

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are risks for not running `DBCC CHECKDB` on the Primary Replica. Brent Ozar goes into details in his article [Can I Offload DBCC CHECKDB To Another Server?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/05/can-i-offload-dbcc-checkdb-to-another-server/), but one big reason being you should check for database corruption on the same server where you take your backups to ensure your backups aren't corrupt as well. Furthermore, it's actually best practice to run `DBCC CHECKDB` on all production servers that have the potential to become the Primary Replica, as discussed in [Where to Run DBCC on Always On Availability Groups](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/02/where-run-dbcc-on-alwayson-availability-groups/).

For some ideas on optimizing `DBCC CHECKB` performance, you can also see this Brent Ozar Article: [3 Ways to Run DBCC CHECKDB Faster](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/08/3-ways-to-run-dbcc-checkdb-faster/).